# ASP.NET MVC - Printing a div that was modified by jQuery after initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

My view has a div that contains multiple tables generated from my model. Each field in each row in this table can be modified (`TextBoxFor` fields). Rows can also be moved between tables and entire new tables can be created in the view as well, all this is done via jQuery. When I submit the form that holds these tables, the correct, modified data is sent back to my controller. However, when the JS is called to open the browser's print window, the contents of the div are what they were before changes were made in the view (i.e., before rows were moved, values changed, new tables created). My print command is called when a submit button is clicked as such:

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    w = window.open();
    w.document.write($('#tables-wrapper').html());
    w.document.close();
    w.focus();
    w.print();
    w.close();
});
```

How would I go about printing the div with its state as at the time of clicking the button, rather than what was originally loaded into the DOM? Is this even possible?

Comment: Print submit button also does the updation ? Is the DOM loaded completely when click the print submit button ? Have you tried giving a timeout so as to  ease rendering?

Comment: It's definitely loaded completely. This isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the contents of #tables-wrapper to a new window, you could print the current window, using CSS media queries to hide unnecessary stuff when printed.

HTML:

```
<div class="noprint">
  <h1>
  Stuff you don't want printed
  </h1>
</div>

<table id="tables-wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="save" value="Save" />

<div class="noprint">
  <h3>
  More stuff you don't want printed
  </h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media print {
  #tables-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #tables-wrapper td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .noprint {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/OsborneSupremacy/9ts56r0z/